# BigQuery update how to get number of updated rows

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions to connect to a Google Bigquery database and update some rows. The cloud function is written using Python 3.

I need help figuring out how to get the result message or the number of updated/changed rows whenever I run an update dml through the function. Any ideas?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def my_update_function(context,data):

    BQ = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = BQ.query("Update table set etc...")
    rows = query_job.result()
    return (rows)
```

I understand that rows always come back as _emptyrowiterator object. Any way i can get result or result message? Documentation says I have to get it from a bigquery job method. But can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `.num_dml_affected_rows` is a nice way for a single (parent) job however, if you have multiple children jobs, `@@row_count` [(system variables)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system_variables) might be also useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that you are searching for `QueryJob.num_dml_affected_rows`. It contain number of rows affected by update or any other DML statement. If you just paste it to your code instead of `rows` in `return` statement you will get number as int or you can create some massage like :

```
return("Number of updated rows: " + str(job_query.num_dml_affected_rows))
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: ohhh thanks. that is a more graceful way of doing it. let me test.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to access the `num_dml_affected_rows` for the children jobs? Currently, my `num_dml_affected_rows` is 0 and I believe it is due to DMLs are done inside children jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no mention in the bigquery Python DB-API documentation on rows returned. https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/reference.html

I decided to use a roundabout method on dealing with this issue by generating a SELECT statement first to check if there are any matches to the WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement.

Example:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import dbapi as bq

def my_update_function(context,data):

        try:
            bq_connection = bq.connect()
            bq_cursor = bq_connection.cursor()
            bq_cursor.execute("select * from table where ID = 1")
            results = bq_cursor.fetchone()

            if results is None:
                print("Row not found.")

            else:
                bq_cursor.execute("UPDATE table set name = 'etc' where ID = 1")
                bq_connection.commit()
                bq_connection.close()

        except Exception as e:
            db_error = str(e)
```