# How to access the DML result of the child job with BigQuery Client?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to check the value of **dml_affected_rows** with BigQuery Client.

I have checked [1], and it works when the query (or DML) contains a single job. However, when the results are written from children's jobs like the below script, the `num_dml_affected_rows` is void. How can I check the child job's `num_dml_affected_rows`. I am think something like below.

> query_job.children_job[-1].num_dml_affected_rows  # (last child dml result)

But couldn't find the right way (or method) to accomplish it from the documents [2, 3].

[1] [BigQuery update how to get number of updated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970341/bigquery-update-how-to-get-number-of-updated-rows)
[2] [BQ REST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get)
[3] [BQ Client API (dev)](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html)

Sample Script (python3)

```py
sql = """
    INSERT `project.dataset.table` (logdatetime)
    SELECT
        CURRENT_DATETIME() as logdatetime
    ;
    SELECT 1
    ;
    INSERT `project.dataset.table` (logdatetime)
    SELECT
        CURRENT_DATETIME() as logdatetime
    ;
"""
query_job = bigquery.Client().query(sql)
query_job.result()
print(query_job.num_child_jobs)  # 3
print(query_job.num_dml_affected_rows)  # None
```

p.s. My current solution is to store the rows counts of `destination table` before and after the DML to check the difference, but this is unnecessary if I am able to directly access DML results of the child job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that works in scripting is the [system variable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#system_variables) @@row_count.

> If used in a script and the previous script statement is DML, specifies the number of rows modified, inserted, or deleted, as a result of that DML statement.

In your case, if you do

```python
sql = """
    INSERT `project.dataset.table` (logdatetime)
    SELECT
        CURRENT_DATETIME() as logdatetime
    ;
    SELECT @@row_count -- output how many row inserted by previous DML
    ;
    INSERT `project.dataset.table` (logdatetime)
    SELECT
        CURRENT_DATETIME() as logdatetime
    ;
    SELECT @@row_count -- output how many row inserted by previous DML
    ;
"""
query_job = bigquery.Client().query(sql)
query_job.result()
print(query_job.num_child_jobs)  # you're getting 4 jobs here
print(query_job.num_dml_affected_rows)  # still None
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit late for the original question but in case someone else stumbles across this, here is my solution:

```
def run_bigquery_query():
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

    sql_query = """ SELECT / INSERT / ... """

    job = bigquery_client.query(sql_query)
    job.result()  # Wait for the whole script to finish

    affected_rows = 0
    for child_job in bigquery_client.list_jobs(parent_job=job.job_id):
        if child_job.num_dml_affected_rows is not None:
            affected_rows += child_job.num_dml_affected_rows

    print("Affected rows: {}".format(affected_rows))
```